# What kind of website needs SSL?

Tags: ssl

What kind of website that needs SSL? Is it  limited to e-commerce website, or websites that needs credit card payment only? Is there another good reason for a non e-commerce website to use SSL?

Thank you for sharing your experience.

Comment: Why a downvote? I don't get it.

Comment: All websites, IMO.

Comment: From the user viewpoint, anything that requires a login or stores personal data, no matter how insignificant you think it is. We're tired of sending our login credentials in plaintext, same goes for our account information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two reasons to use SSL:

1. You want to encrypt data in transit.
2. You want some level of assurance that the server you are connecting to belongs to whom you think it belongs to.

Encryption isn't very useful if you do not trust the entity on the other side. When you give the keys to your car to a valet, you trust that the person isn't going to steal your car because he's wearing a uniform and is standing in front of a restaurant. If some random dude offered to park your car, you probably wouldn't hand the keys over.

The trust/assurance part is complicated in that there are numerous vendors selling SSL certs with little or validation of identity. Verisign and others have tried to improve this (and make more money) with things like Extended Validation certificates. Entities like the US Military and MIT do use SSL to restrict access to specific website to individuals or computers with certificates issued by a trusted CA.

Answer (score 8):

In simple terms, SSL is used when you don't want the traffic to be in clear text. For example, a web site which requires a user to enter a password should use SSL, otherwise anyone seeing the traffic can also see what is being sent.

Answer (score 4):

any time you are sending or receiving personal information, you'll want an SSL certificate.  It could be if you are running an ecommerce site, job application site (requesting a SSN), email server (corporate or public), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's for privacy mostly.
And users like their privacy very much.

But mainly, you would want it if you sell anything on your website.
Or additionally, if you have users private/personal information hosted on your site - mostly when they submit their data, to ensure some third party isn't getting it's hands on it.

Answer (score 0):

Security? ;)

I have SSL for my gateway computer - VPN, but most important HTTPS when logging into email web interfaces, intranet gateway etc.

Whenever some safety is needed, usage of a SSL certificate makes a LOT of sense.

Answer (score 0):

SSL refers to Secure Socket layer. Whenever you visit any credit-card transaction sites or any banking sites or may be any online shopping site the gateway is more secure. Thus they use HTTPS rather than HTTP. If you have noticed, now a days even the Gmail Login is HTTPS, this is done to secure your data in more encrypted form and with secure connection.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.sslshopper.com/article-do-i-need-an-ssl-certificate-for-my-website.html